# Execute ajax foreach element in array

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, jquery-ajax

I have function like this:

```
function sendEmail() {

var appweburl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";


var fieldName = "Notificar a";
var body = "Descripción";
var _body = $("textarea[title^='" + body + "']");

var fullURL = window.location.href
var url = new URL(fullURL ); 
var ID = url.searchParams.get("ID");


var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
var emailSpan = $(_PeoplePicker).find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan');
var _sid ="";
var arrEmailID = [];

if (emailSpan.length > 0) {


$(emailSpan).each((index,el) => {
 arrEmailID.push(`'${$(el).attr('sid').split("|")[2]}'`);
});

} else {
       alert("null");
}

        var fieldUsuario = _sid;
        var fromMail = 'emaik@domain.com';
        var subject = 'Tarea Editada: ' + 'ID: ' +ID + ' ' + _body.val();
        var body = 'Se ha editado la tarea: '+ 'ID: ' + ID+ ' ' + 'Descripción: ' + _body.val() ;    

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': fromMail,
                'To': { 'results': [arrEmailID] },
                'Body': body, 
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }
      ),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d.results;

        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see I have `var arrEmailID = [];` it populates foreach `emailSpan` I receive, so at the final of the day I have something like this:
[image]

I want to know if its possible to execute ajax call foreach item `arrEmailID` and use that item in   `To': { 'results': [arrEmailID] },`

Comment: You mean you want to send individual emails? and not include everyone in one email?

Comment: Yes I want it because I cant add multiple emails  in `To`, I try to send into alot of formats but it just don´t works, so now I want to send individual emails, how can I achieve it?  @Rothrock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only done this in SP 2013 on-prem. So there may be slight differences. First thing I notice is that in your array of recipients you've got both double and single quotes. So that probably isn't quite right. I have used `SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail` to send:

```
["i:0#.w|<domain>\<userId>", "i:0#.w|<domain>\<userId>"]
```

I know that will need to be different for SP Online, but I don't know exactly how. But it should only have one set of quotation marks around each element.

But here is the part for making multiple rest calls. Looking at your code I think you are using jQuery to handle the ajax portion of your call, so that is what my code is using too. I'm also going to get rid of the success and fail callbacks and make use of the deffered/promises included in `$.ajax`. You will need to rearrange your code a bit. Basically take the part that sets up and gets all your variables into one function and then passes them to the send function.

```
  var appweburl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
  var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
  var headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
  };

  function prepareEmails() {

      // code to get users info configure the body and subect

      // this pattern allows for multiple REST calls
      var promises =[];

      arrEmailID.forEach(function(recipient){

          promises.push(sendEmail(recipient,fromMail,body,subject));

      });

      // this will resolve when all of the promises are resolved
      return $.when.apply(null,promises);
  }


  function sendEmail(recipient, fromMail, body, subject) {

      // if recipient isn't an array make it one
      recipient = Array.isArray(tmp) ? recipient : [recipient];

      var payload = {'properties': {
                        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'},
                        'From': fromMail,
                        'To': {'results': recipient},
                        'Body': body,
                        'Subject': subject
                      }
      };

      return $.ajax({
          contentType: 'application/json',
          url: urlTemplate,
          type: "POST",
          headers: headers,
          data: JSON.stringify(payload)
      });
  }

  ...

  // kick it all off later with

  function sendNotices(e){
    prepareEmails()
      .done(function(){

        // if there were multiple rest calls there will be multiple results
        // if there was only one there won't be

        var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        if(!Array.isArray(results[0])){
          results = [results];  
        }

        // do whatever you need to do with the results from each call

      })
      .fail(function(err){
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
      });
  }

button.addEventListener('click',sendNotices);
```

Comment: I try it as you say, but when it hit line   `recipient = Array.isArray(tmp) ? recipient : [recipient];`, it says tmp is not defined.. What should be tmp? it should be actual `recipient`?

Comment: IT WORKS!, only one problem.. when EditForm loading function executes and I only want to execute only when I press button so I use `button.addEventListener('click', function() { prepareEmails(); });`, but how can I do to no execute in page load?

Comment: The part down at the bottom that says // kick it all off later. I might wrap that in a function with some other name and that is what I would call from your click. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 1):

It should work by adding a `;` between each emails:

```
'To': { 'results': arrEmailID.join("; ") },
```

For example : `abc@abc.com; test@abc.com; ta@abc.com; tessss@abc.com`

If it doesn't work, then you can send emails one by one using `PromiseChain` function below:

```
function PromiseChain(arr, fct) {
  var dfd = jQuery.Deferred().resolve();
  var res = arr.map(function(item,idx) {
    dfd = dfd.then(function() {
      return fct(item,idx)
    });
    return dfd
  });
  return jQuery.when.apply(null, res)
}

function sendEmail() {
  var appweburl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
  var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";

  var fieldName = "Notificar a";
  var body = "Descripción";
  var _body = $("textarea[title^='" + body + "']");

  var fullURL = window.location.href
  var url = new URL(fullURL );
  var ID = url.searchParams.get("ID");

  var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
  var emailSpan = $(_PeoplePicker).find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan');
  var _sid ="";
  var arrEmailID = [];

  if (emailSpan.length > 0) {
    $(emailSpan).each((index,el) => {
     arrEmailID.push(`'${$(el).attr('sid').split("|")[2]}'`);
    });
  } else {
    alert("null");
  }

  var fieldUsuario = _sid;
  var fromMail = 'emaik@domain.com';
  var subject = 'Tarea Editada: ' + 'ID: ' +ID + ' ' + _body.val();
  var body = 'Se ha editado la tarea: '+ 'ID: ' + ID+ ' ' + 'Descripción: ' + _body.val() ;

  // use PromiseChain here with "arrEmailID"
  PromiseChain(arrEmailID, function(email) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: urlTemplate,
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
          '__metadata': {
            'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
          },
          'From': fromMail,
          'To': {
            'results': email
          },
          'Body': body,
          'Subject': subject
        }
      }),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var result = data.d.results;
        console.log("Email sent to "+email)
        deferred.resolve()
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        deferred.reject()
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      url:'http://api.jQuery.com/'+item,
      success:function(data, textStatus) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        deferred.resolve()
      },
      error:function() {
        deferred.reject()
      }
    })
    return deferred;
  }).done(function() {
    var nbEmails = arguments.length;
    alert(nbEmails + " email"+(nbEmails>1?"s":"")+" sent !")
  })
}
```